# Can't play Minecraft 1.7.5 - sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

For some reason my PC can't download `authlib/1.3.1/authlib-1.3.1.jar` for job 'Version & Libraries'.

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Development Console:

```
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.ChecksummedDownloadable.download(ChecksummedDownloadable.java:49) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:108) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching libraries.minecraft.net found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    ... 22 more
[19:37:39 ERROR]: Gave up trying to download https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/mojang/authlib/1.3.1/authlib-1.3.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
[19:37:40 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\No need to know :)\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.5\1.7.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Used own copy as it matched etag
[19:37:40 ERROR]: Job 'Version & Libraries' finished with 1 failure(s)! (took 0:00:03.305)
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently Minecraft servers are down. Please read this article that Notch tweeted about earlier...

> We temporarily took down our servers due to this: http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/04/critical-crypto-bug-in-openssl-opens-two-thirds-of-the-web-to-eavesdropping/ … A LOT of websites and services are affected by this. Be careful.
>    - @notch

If you have logged in to Minecraft within the past 24 hours, please change your password. Follow notch on twitter to get all of the latest updates straight from him.

Comment: Were this to occur at any other time it might be a good idea to delete (or move) your .minecraft folder. You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack and any files in that folder may have been compromised. To be safer I'd delete them for sure.